# jquery mobile text overlaying text weird button

Tags: jquery, css, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

The text displays like if it were over another text, overlaying it in some way. That is at least what is seems to me. 
Does anybody know what might be happening?
Pic: http://imgur.com/IUamsPA
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/km3Lp60q/

This is the raw html for the popup in where the problem is:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="loginPopup" class="ui-content loginPopup logregPopup" data-dismissible="false" data-shadow="true">
        <form>
            <div style="padding:10px 20px;">

                <a id="registerLnk" href=""> Register </a>
                <br>

                <h3>Please sign in</h3>
                <label for="username" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="user" id="username" value="" placeholder="username">
                <label for="password" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="password" value="" placeholder="password">
                <input type="button" value="ok" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-left ui-icon-check" data-inline="true"><!-- TODO: Fix the icon -->
                <input type="button" value="Facebook" class="ui-btn ui-btn" id="facebookBtn" data-theme="d">
                <input type="button" value="Google" class="ui-btn" id="googleBtn" data-theme="e">


            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I have some custom themes made in the themeroller, the problem appears when I use data-theme="x" (or any of the variants).

Comment: Your JSFiddle is empty for me. About your text, it seems the white font has a white shadow too. Please check the computed style in Chrome/FF developer console

Comment: Try setting the text-shadow css to none.

Comment: Thanks, the text-shadow is set to none from previous tries to fix it. Do you have any idea why the jsfiddle clear itself? I've also tried chrome developer console but for some reason if I open it somewhere outside the emulator or the phone, it just stays loading (gray circle spinning), do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Here is a Fiddle you can fork: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/btr8nqyL/ I am unable to replicate the problem since we do not have the rolled themes. I would revert to built in themes first, test everything, and then apply your custom themes. If it breaks, then something in your theme is causing an issue.

Comment: Indeed the data theme was causing an issue, and the source was, as suggested, the text shadow attribute. Setting it to none didn't removed it, it just removed the color, which in default is white, just as font. The otther parameters of the text shadow were the issue, I then entered w3school and copied every parameter to 0/none.

Answer (score 0):

The text shadow attribute was the problem. Setting it to none didn't removed it, it just removed the color, which in default is white, just as the font. The other parameters of the text shadow were the issue. After the discovery,  I entered w3school and copied every parameter to 0/none.